# How should I structure in Strut2?

Tags: database-design, data-structures, struts2

I just have worked with Struts2, so I have many questions.

On JSP: `<s:text name="account"/>`.

On action class:

```java
    public String getAccount() {
            return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(String account) {
    this.account = account;
    }
```

1/ Account is a attribute of Student. When I submit to server, is the getter and setter will receive and send the information to client?

2/ I want to insert a new Student with two attributes: account and email. After the insertion is completed, user will be redirected a jsp that show student table.
   If the action class want to get account  and email parameter from jsp, do the action class need  two field account, email with getter and setter? If it need, is the Student class that only contains gettter and setter method necessary?

Actually, It has 4 fields.
Action class:

```java
public class TraineeLogin {
      private String account;
      private String fName;
      private String lName;
      private String email;
      private Vector<Trainee> listTrainee; //Should I use 4 lists or 1 list to contain infomation?

      public String execute(){
              DBTraineesManager manager  = new DBTraineesManager();
              ...//valid
              manager.addOrUpdate(account, fName, lName, email);
              return "success";
          }

        public String getAccount() {
            return account;
        }
        public void setAccount(String account) {
            this.account = account;
        }
        public String getfName() {
            return fName;
        }
        public void setfName(String fName) {
            this.fName = fName;
        }
        public String getlName() {
            return lName;
        }
        public void setlName(String lName) {
            this.lName = lName;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        public Vector<Trainee> getListTrainee() {
            return listTrainee;
        }
        public void setListTrainee(Vector<Trainee> listTrainee) {
            this.listTrainee = listTrainee;
        }


        }
```

Entity class:

```java
public class Trainee {
    private String account;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String email;

    constructor();   
    getter();     //That same as DBTraineesManager class.
    setter();     // The code is same. It wasted time.
}
```

3/ Should I use two lists: listAccount and listEmail for showing a table? Or I should use listStudent?

4/ What is the best structure for maintain database to query and update a object in Strut2?

Comment: The structure to maintain database is SQL. Post the code that you tried.

Comment: Maybe, I did not ask clearly. Should I do to load database on jsp by struts 2? Main question is 2 and 3.

Comment: My database is only one table.

Comment: It couldn't be one as for you have different classes with associations you'd better use ORM (Object Relational Mapping) to map it to the schema of the database. IMHO you can do it with Hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you do not need to put your **getter and Setter** in both class . you can put it either in action class or separate  Bean class which takes the forms input   .
IN my view you should use only one list to manage all attributes.

Third part of you question is about data base designing pattern .For it is better to follow **DAO** designing pattern

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object

http://www.tutorials4u.net/struts2-tutorial/struts2_crud_example.html